# Нужна помощь с меню и навигацией JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите прописать скрипт JS для того чтобы выходило меню слева и при клике на крестик уходило обратно,и кликая в этом меню например на секцию 2 оно прокручивалось на 2 секцию,новичок в этом деле,не могу понять как делать(

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: thin;
}

#main {
  background-color: #ff5722;
}

#news {
  background-color: #1e88e5;
}

#feedback {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

#maps {
  background-color: #fb8c00;
}

.menu-link {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.menu-link span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.menu-link span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.menu-link span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

.menu-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-link:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-33deg);
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu-link:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(31deg);
  width: 12px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.active-menu {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 3;
}

li a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.close-btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 53%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.close-btn:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="menu-link">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <section id="main">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №1</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="news">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №2</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="feedback">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №3</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="maps">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №4</h2>
  </section>

  <menu>
    <a class="close-btn" href="#close">&times;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#main">Секция №1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Секция №2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#feedback">Секция №3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#maps">Секция №4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотреть лучше на полно-экранном режиме.

Изменения:
Я добавил translate: -100% в отдельный класс и добавил его к меню.
После при необходимости от действий в обработчике он или добавляется или удаляется (toggleClass('translate')); Происходит это по такому принципу. Если класс есть, он удаляется. Если нет, добавляется.

На счет скролла страницы почитай статьи в сети. Их предостаточно.
Ну а если в кратце то e.preventDefaul(); - отменяем стандартное поведение браузера, а конкретно переход по ссылке.
Далее берем содержимое созданного мной атрибута. И на его основе ищем положение блока с таким id на странице. Прячем меню. Пролистываем страницу до этого положения. Done.

```js
$('.menu-link, .close-btn').on('click', function(){
 $('menu').toggleClass('translate');
});

$('menu').on('click','a', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var flag = $(this).attr('alias');
  var position = $(''+flag+'').offset().top;
  $('menu').toggleClass('translate');
  $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: position}, 2000);// это скорость прокрутки страницы
});
```

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: thin;
}

#main {
  background-color: #ff5722;
}

#news {
  background-color: #1e88e5;
}

#feedback {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}

#maps {
  background-color: #fb8c00;
}

.menu-link {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.menu-link span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.menu-link span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.menu-link span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(6px);
}

.menu-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-link:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-33deg);
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu-link:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(31deg);
  width: 12px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.translate{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.active-menu {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 3;
}

li a {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.close-btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 53%;
  display: block;
  line-height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
}

.close-btn:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="menu-link">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <section id="main">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №1</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="news">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №2</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="feedback">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №3</h2>
  </section>
  <section id="maps">
    <h2 class="text-center">Секция №4</h2>
  </section>

  <menu class="translate">
    <a class="close-btn" href="#close">&times;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" alias="#main">Секция №1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" alias="#news">Секция №2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" alias="#feedback">Секция №3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" alias="#maps">Секция №4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
</body>
```